# Confusing Angle Brackets < something > in c++

Tags: c++, brackets

I am coming from c to c++ and familiar with the syntax. But I just came across the code with syntax im not familiar with

```
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr < CommonAPI::Runtime > runtime = CommonAPI::Runtime::get();
    std::shared_ptr<HelloWorldProxy<>> myProxy =
        runtime->buildProxy<HelloWorldProxy>("local", "test");
```

Can Someone explain what does syntax `something < something > something` do also what does syntax `something<something<>> something` do.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates

Comment: in `foo<T>`, `foo` is a template and `T` is the template parameter. In `foo<>` there is probably a default for the template parameter

Comment: C and C++ are different languages - they share a lot of syntax but there's plenty of differences. You should not assume it's an easy transition

Comment: Well I tried googling angle brackets but couldnt find much help before posting here on stacksoverflow. Now it makes so much sense . Thanks!

Comment: @ShreyasMurali: It is merely showing disapproval of a trial & error learning approach which tries to skip reading books and tutorials.

Comment: +1 because templates are deeper into the language, c++ is vast, and sometimes you just need a hint at what you are encountering to move up the learning curve. (although the "I am familiar with the syntax" is clearly a misstatement and OP should feel bad.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking at [C++ templates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(C%2B%2B)).

> ...allows a function or class to work on many different data types without being rewritten for each one.